# How do you graph multiple items in a dataframe on one graph using pandas and matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The dataframe I am trying to graph is below. I want to plot each fieldname as the legend item with **x=year** and **y=value**

The name of the dataframe is `my_gross`

```
                     fieldName thisType         value  year
0   diluted_shares_outstanding     unit  9.637900e+07  2015
1   diluted_shares_outstanding     unit  8.777500e+07  2016
2   diluted_shares_outstanding     unit  8.556200e+07  2017
3   diluted_shares_outstanding     unit  8.353000e+07  2018
4   diluted_shares_outstanding     unit  7.771000e+07  2019
5   diluted_shares_outstanding     unit  7.292900e+07  2020
6                          eps    gross  7.360470e+08  2015
7                          eps    gross  7.285207e+08  2016
8                          eps    gross  8.944702e+08  2017
9                          eps    gross  1.298734e+09  2018
10                         eps    gross  1.451550e+09  2019
11                         eps    gross  1.259110e+09  2020
18               sales_revenue    gross  5.817000e+09  2015
19               sales_revenue    gross  5.762000e+09  2016
20               sales_revenue    gross  6.641000e+09  2017
21               sales_revenue    gross  8.047000e+09  2018
22               sales_revenue    gross  9.351000e+09  2019
23               sales_revenue    gross  8.530000e+09  2020
```

The following code is what I ran to create a graph, but I get undesired results.

```
for item in my_gross['fieldName']:
    plt.plot(my_gross['year'], my_gross['value'],label=item)

plt.legend()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Results
[undesired graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y3R9.png)

The result I am trying to get is similar to this graph
[desired graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bwtt.png)

Do I need to create a dictionary for unique values and do some sort of count and then loop through that dictionary instead of the `df` itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `pandas` and `matplotlib` approach is to [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to wide-form and [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

```
plot_df = df.pivot(index='year',
                   columns='fieldName',
                   values='value')

plot_df.plot()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

`plot_df`:

```
fieldName  diluted_shares_outstanding           eps  sales_revenue
year                                                              
2015                       96379000.0  7.360470e+08   5.817000e+09
2016                       87775000.0  7.285207e+08   5.762000e+09
2017                       85562000.0  8.944702e+08   6.641000e+09
2018                       83530000.0  1.298734e+09   8.047000e+09
2019                       77710000.0  1.451550e+09   9.351000e+09
2020                       72929000.0  1.259110e+09   8.530000e+09
```

[image: plot 1 matplotlib]

---

[`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) has built-in functionality with `hue` without needing to reshape:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='year', y='value', hue='fieldName')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2 seaborn]

Comment: Is this not just tidy form?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Answer (score 1):

There're several ways to do it, depending on libraries available.

Using just `pandas` (with `matplotlib` being used by pandas in backend):

Loop over unique values in your 'fieldName' column, filter the DataFrame to only include that value, set index to year (this will be your x-axis), and choose the value you intent to plot ('value' Series), then plot it.

```
for fieldname in df['fieldName'].unique():
    df[df['fieldName'] == fieldname].set_index('year')['value'].plot(label = fieldname)
plt.legend()
```

Outputs:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Seems like a relatively simple groupby works (no loops needed):

```
df.set_index('year').groupby('fieldName')['value'].plot()
plt.legend()
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps grouping by the field names and then iterating?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you mean, but a relatively simple groupby seems to work. Gonna add an edit, see if that was your idea.

Comment: `for i, subdf in df.groupby('fieldName'): ...`

Comment: @ifly6 there actually seems no need to loop over it

Comment: The simpler groupby with plot is clever, I like it

Comment: Yeah although I think the answer by @Henry Ecker is the better one (and usually what I do in such case, don't know why I didn't think of it first), going to leave this here because  pandas functionality sometimes surprises me :)